# iOS Storyboard: UITableView has mysterious padding before cells

Tags: ios, xcode

This is driving me bonkers. I had one UITableView, copied and pasted it. The second one has no top padding before the first cell, the first one does. There are no mysterious Views in the stack, either. What is going on? I'm going mad and don't want to delete the UITableView and setup all the delegates again. See?

[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE** well, putting this chunk in my `viewDidLoad` method fixes it, but I don't know why and it feels hacky as all get out:

`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

Answer (score 1):

The padding, I believe, is meant to be behind the nav bar, so when it's translucent you'll still see some of the table when you scroll, but the starting point of the first cell would be under the navigation bar.

Changing the View Controller's `Top Bar` property (in Attributes Inspector) to `Opaque Navigation Bar`, would hide that padding from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Does this unwanted space occur when you run the application? If yes you might need to implement a method like,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 0; 
}
```

I experienced this problem before and don't know why but Objective-C sometimes adds header by default, you can eliminate it by explicitly setting header height to zero.

Comment: It does appear. I've added your code and it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change UITableView Style as plain